# reverse objects of objects angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, arrayobject

Currently I am stuck in a problem  where i have some questions and keys in data
I want to display the data is such a way that first my key should appear then my data the problem is in my data

```
    {
  "0": [
    {
      "question": "How often is real property re-assessed (or revalued)?",
      "id": 1,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often second?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often third?",
      "id": 2,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "key": "Survey Meta Data"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "question": "When are New Assessment Notices sent out?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Assessment"
    }
  ]
}
```

when i use ng-repeat with this data i got something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in viewQuestions">
<div class="panel panel-default"  ng-repeat="value in data">
     {{value.key}}

   label>{{value.question}} </label>

     </div>
      </div>
```

my questions are displayed first and then key is displayed but ***I want to display the key first and then the questions***
**I know the problem** the questions are displayed first because they are at the inserted first then data key.

Is there any method that i can reverse the data so **key** is displayed first then my **questions**

Answer (score 0):

What you need is data massaging to change the data structure to the format that you need.

```
var processedData = [];
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
  var section = { questions: [] };

  angular.forEach(data, function(question) {
    if (question.key) { // this is key, not question
      section.key = question.key;
    }
    else {
      section.questions.push(question);
    }
  });

  processedData.push(section);
});
```

Comment: question .key is nothing its data.question

Comment: @KumailHussain You have array of arrays in your data, you may need to combine them?

Comment: what you mean by combine??

Answer (score 0):

After digging up I came up with a solution that works perfectly fine:
first reverse the array using this filter:

```
 .filter("reverse", function(){
    return function(items){
        return items.slice().reverse(); // Create a copy of the array and reverse the order of the items
    };
});
```

and in html just add this line

```
<div class="panel panel-default"  ng-repeat="value in data |reverse">
```

now key will be displayed first then the questions